# How to create an interactive sql query in R with reactive component

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to get a value from a user and create a query with the dynamic value in an rmd file with the following code:

````
```{r  }
returnSQLDS<-function(sqlQuery, rdsFileName){
  library(RODBC)
  cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="myconnectionstring")
  resultSet <- sqlQuery(cn,sqlQuery)
  odbcClose(cn)
  return (resultSet)
}
h1("Choose your lookup")
inputPanel(
 textInput("whichlookup", "Which lookup items do you wish to view?", "States")

)


renderDataTable(runif(input$whichlookup),(reactive({
  sql ="SELECT LookupId , Lookup.LookupTableId , ItemId , ItemName , ItemDescription FROM   LookupTable INNER JOIN dbo.Lookup ON Lookup.LookupTableId = LookupTable.LookupTableId WHERE  Name = '"
  sql=paste(sql,input$whichlookup,sep="")
  sql=paste(sql,"'",sep="")
  returnSQLDS( sql) #calls the SQL database with correct connection details
  })))


```
````

It keeps dying on the sql statement. Which leads me to believe I can't have a variable be set in the reactive section. Can anyone tell how I can modify this code to achieve the goal of allowing a user to contribute to the dynamic sql query?
Note-I will not be using a text search for a where clause in the final product I am just trying to get the mechanics correct so I can add my select list of proper values but even those will be sent to a stored procedure.

Comment: This is really bad, don't do this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. For example, perhaps I wanted to look up a state named `None';delete from lookuptable;commit;`. See also https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Thanks, I agree. The end goal is for this to be a list which goes to SQL Stored Proc (which I can make immune to SQL injection) but I really need to get this syntax so I can send parameters to SQL Stored procs.And more importantly this is not a public facing item but is being used for a conversion from 1 database to another database by myself with the Markdown provider notes and reasoning for the conversion.

Comment: Can you include what the function `returnSQLDS` does? I'm not familiar with that function.

Comment: It is just a function that I use to call the sql database with the proper crenditials that returns a dataset.

Comment: I use parameterized SQL queries frequently enough in shiny, so there is nothing inherent in the concept. Do you see any console messages? It would help to capture the call to `returnSQLDS` and see if it throws any warnings or errors. Similarly, it might help to know which SQL client package you're using.

Comment: I have added the function to the question. If you have an example of allowing a customer to select a parameter and send to an SP in Shiny that would be helpful for me (That is the answer as far as I am concerned)